# Microsoft Word 2010: "replace all" with same word + something else

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I want to find all bolded words and replace them with the same word, unbolded, but with a symbol after it indicating that it was bolded.

So for example

Yesterday, **love** was **such** an easy game to **play**.

Would become something like:

Yesterday, love(b) was such(b) an easy game to play(b).

I know how to find all bolded words, but I'm having trouble replacing it with the same word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: 1]

[Had to insert some text to meet the minimum requirements, although none was required.]

Answer (score 0):

Need use Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 and regular expression.

See:

[MSWord macro: search and highlight formatted text patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766123/msword-macro-search-and-highlight-formatted-text-patterns)

[Search for a special number vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782491/search-for-a-special-number-vb-net)

Comment: "Need use Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 and regular expression." - Absolutely no need!

Comment: @Karan Well, you're back faster and more accurately, most likely it's a tradition, I still think) I feel closer to the mass script based way)).

Comment: I love the challenge of crafting a good script any day, but why waste precious time and effort when it's not required, right? :)

Comment: @Karan Ok, for this is optional).